# Object doesn't move to another hemisphere in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to realize moving on an object round sphere (walk on it), but when it gets to the equator of the sphere, it stops moving.

```
public Transform planet;
public bool AlignToPlanet;
public float gravityConstant = -9.8f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 toCenter = planet.position - transform.position;
    toCenter.Normalize();

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(toCenter * 9.8f, ForceMode.Acceleration);

    if (AlignToPlanet)
    {
        Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(-transform.up, -toCenter);
        q = q * transform.rotation;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, 1);
    }

    Debug.Log(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 2, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should avoid calling `GetComponent` more than necessary. Just call it once to get the `Rigidbody` in `Awake` then refer to the result in `FixedUpdate`.

Second, once you determine the object's up direction, you can use cross products to determine what would be the forward that is closest to the previous forward while still maintaining that up.

Then, you can use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to set that up and forward.

Finally, you should use [Rigidbody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) to set the rotation.

Altogether:

```
private Rigidbody rb;
public Transform planet;
public bool AlignToPlanet;
public float gravityConstant = -9.8f;

void Awake() 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 toCenter = planet.position - transform.position;
    toCenter.Normalize();

    rb.AddForce(toCenter * 9.8f, ForceMode.Acceleration);

    if (AlignToPlanet)
    {
        Vector3 newUp = -toCenter;
        Vector3 newRight = Vector3.Cross(newUp, transform.forward);
        Vector3 newForward = Vector3.Cross(newRight, newUp);

        Quaternion newRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(newForward, newUp);
        rb.MoveRotation(q);
    }

    Debug.Log(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 2, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: Object goes to the center of sphere and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a new project with your script, and it works fine for me.

The only things I changed (beside the `AddForce` on the forward to test it) are :

- The `FromToRotation`in which you pass opposite vectors (one to the up, and one to the down)
- The `Slerp` I removed, it is useless since you pass a value of 1.

So, it looks like this :

```cs
if (AlignToPlanet)
{
    // removed the minus in front of toCenter
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(-transform.up, toCenter); 
    transform.rotation = q * transform.rotation;
}
```

**EDIT**
I agree with @Ruzhim : the `LookRotation` is a better way to compute your new rotation, since it takes also the forward of your object.
(And for the fact to not use the GetComponent in any Update)